# Commenting protocol

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm just looking for some feedback on commenting on other's answers. I asked a question a couple of weeks back. I didn't get a really good answer, so I spent some time and provided an answer to my own question.

A couple of days ago someone provided another answer, but I felt like it didn't add anything additional to the answer that I'd provided. The answer also had comments in it like "you shouldn't do this", when my question explicitly stated that I was looking for alternative solution, i.e My question: "I'm looking for an alternative to A." His answer: "You shouldn't use A, because it's a bad idea."

To paraphrase, my comment to his answer was something like this, "Why did you post this answer? You've added nothing to the conversation. You also didn't try to understand, or even read, the question before answering and you didn't read my answer."

I felt my response was valid and impassive. Apparently there were a number of people who didn't agree as my comment was deleted. I did apologize to the user if I came off as being rude and then explained why I thought he shouldn't have posted that answer.

My questions are, should responses like this be made in the comments? Is the tone of my response inappropriate for SO, or any other SE site?

Comment: [This is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19282263/1043380), for people wondering.

Comment: Of your paraphrased comment, the first two sentences seem generally appropriate.  The last two are more just rude and not constructive.  They could really be phrased more appropriately, but really they should probably just not be there.  And of course I couldn't comment on the appropriateness of the deleted comment as I don't know how it differs from your paraphrased version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "We judge ourselves by our intentions and others by their behaviour." ― Stephen M.R. Covey.

I think people are looking at your comment as an attack or, at the very least, a declaration of bad-faith on the part of the answerer.

You're making accusations of actions (or non-actions). "You...didn't try to understand..." Really? You know that for sure?

I think, perhaps, assuming *good faith* on the part of the answerer, and perhaps a little diplomacy, would have served you well.

> I'm not clear why you posted this answer. It doesn't appear to add anything to the conversation. Further, it seems like you misunderstood, or mis-read, the question. Also, I did add an answer myself and this answer doesn't seem to improve upon it at all or offer a viable alternative.

Perhaps it's too mealy-mouthed for some, but at least it's blaming the misunderstanding on miscommunication (which *could* have been on your side) rather than malice or stupidity on the other person's part.

Perhaps, though, a simple "I'm afraid this doesn't work for me (because of A, B, and C)." and a downvote would be better. All-too-often people take what were intended to be helpful, constructive comments and internalize them, resulting in arguments.

Addendum: Another thing to keep in mind: Stack Overflow reaches quite an international audience with wide variations in skill with English. What you consider a neutral tone may not seem so to someone from a different culture or who doesn't have the same level of proficiency in the language. One thing I always try to do: with my responses, I re-read them back to myself and try to find the worst possible interpretation. For someone else's response to me, I try to read it with the most positive interpretation.

Comment: You obviously don't understand...jk. These are very good points and I'll definitely take them into account.

Comment: Too many "perhaps" in there.

Comment: @AlEverett - Perhaps.

Comment: *"Stack Overflow reaches quite an international audience with wide variations in skill with English. What you consider a neutral tone may not seem so to someone from a different culture or who doesn't have the same level of proficiency in the language."* You should bold this section. Perhaps (ha ha) communication on the Internet would improve if people would consider this before writing anything.

Answer (score 7):

> Why did you post this answer? You've added nothing to the conversation. You also didn't try to understand, or even read, the question before answering and you didn't read my answer.

This sounds a bit rude to me. You could have said something like this instead:

> My question was about X but your answer addresses Y. I've added my solution above, but thanks for answering.

Or something similar.

When someone posts an answer to your question, you can:

- Upvote it
- Accept it
- Downvote it (and optionally explain why)

In this case, you could've just added a comment as mentioned above, but it's upto you to decide whether or not to downvote it.

> My questions are, should responses like this be made in the comments? Is the tone of my response inappropriate for SO, or any other SE site?

I may not be right, but my suggestion is to be a little more polite to those who try to help you. :)

Comment: you're right and that's a good philosophy to follow, in any case.